# FBGraph API wont give publish permissions to other Users in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB Graph API in iOS application to post a message from application. I am able to login and post message successfully. But when another user logged in and try to make post it getting error.

I set up APP setting in FBDEVELOPER site as **STATUS & REVIEW** --> and set as **APPLICATION PUBLIC** aslo.

I dont know why its happening. Will you please help me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your app isn't reviewed yet I guess: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening since- from [v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, developers need to submit the app for reviewing if the app is requesting more than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` permission.

See here for the [login review guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).

Comment: Thanks For your Response.
How to submit my app for Review.

Comment: Detailed steps are mentioned in the link from this section onwards- *Step 1: Create a submission*

Comment: how much time it will take to review the app after i submited?

Comment: Its mentioned in the link itself. *"The review time estimate will change based on the requested permissions, ranging between 7 to 14 business days."*